# Using Snakemake on a SLURM cluster with CONDA_ROOT

Tags: conda, cluster-computing, slurm, snakemake

I am using Snakemake on our Slurm cluster and running into the following issue:

To use Conda in a Slurmjob on our cluster I always have to set the following in the job script:

```
# Insert this after any #SLURM commands
export CONDA_ROOT=$HOME/mambaforge
. $CONDA_ROOT/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
export PATH="$CONDA_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
# but naturally before using any python scripts
```

Now I want to use a Snakefile with multiple conda enviroments like this:

```
rule test:
    input:
    output:
    conda:
        "example"
    resources:
    params:
    shell:
```

However because this does not export the above conda cannot be found: `/bin/bash: conda: command not found`

I could simply add the above exports at the beginning at every `shell` segment, but this is messy. What is the proper way to configure Snakemake?

Comment: To try to narrow the issue, what happens if you submit a test job that simply activates a conda environment (no snakemake involved at all here)? I wonder if the issue is how you installed conda or how your cluster is configured. Tipically you shouldn't need any special configuration for snakemake.

Comment: I'll also add that putting those commands at the top of your shell won't help; the conda env activates before control reaches shell.  I've never had problems with installing conda/mamba locally and running snakemake on a cluster, may be easier than troubleshooting these modules.

Comment: @dariober If I do not add anything to a jobscript except conda activate test I get the following error: `/var/spool/slurm/job42792011/slurm_script:24: command not found: conda
python not found` I always need to do the export I wrote on top to get it to activate properly.

Comment: @TroyComi I mean remove the conda part and activate it via a shell block. What do you mean with installing mamba locally?

Comment: It seems the issue is not related to snakemake but perhaps to your conda installation. What happens if on the headnode you execute `conda --help`. How did you install conda? Maybe reinstalling conda altogether could fix it and once you are at it I'd suggest going for [mamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/mamba-installation.html)

Comment: @dariober Both mamba and conda are correctly installed and behave as expected on the headnote. It might be that the observed behavior is a particularity of our cluster and I should contact the IT-department. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the jobscript template that snakemake submits can be freely edited. I put the following in there and now the script is unclutered and works:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/zsh
export CONDA_ROOT=$HOME/mambaforge
. $CONDA_ROOT/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
export PATH="$CONDA_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
{exec_job}
```